# Why can't I parse this string to date?

Tags: c#, string, parsing, datetime

I am trying to parse a string to a DateTime:

```
string datum = "13/7/2013";
DateTime dtDatum = DateTime.ParseExact(datum, "yyyy-d-M", CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("nl-NL"));
```

I'm getting "FormatException was unhandled by user code". I've tried several formats, and also different CultureInfo's, but nothing seems to work. I've searched on Google and this website, but can't seem to find an answer that gets rid of the exception.

Help is much appreciated.

Comment: Try: ´datum, "dd/MM/yyyy", ´

Comment: @Marek will it work for November?

Comment: What do you think `"yyyy-d-M"` means?

Comment: "dd/M/yyyy" gives the same error.

Comment: Why do you expect this code to be working? The format you specified is completely different from the date format

Answer (score 3):

Your input format is not the same as the ["format specifier that defines the required format of"](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w2sa9yss.aspx) the input.

> The DateTime.ParseExact(String, String, IFormatProvider) method parses the string representation of a date, which must be in the format defined by the format parameter.

So your input would need to be `string datum = "2013/13/7";`; for this to match your format specifier.

Comment: jayce: Your provided format is yyyy-d-M and date has a **year** at the **end**, not mentioning the '-' vs '/' collision. Note that you use 'ParseExact' so the data is required to match **exactly** to egt parsed.

Answer (score 2):

Do not specify format, culture will do the job:

```
string datum = "13/7/2013";
DateTime dtDatum = DateTime.Parse(datum, CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("nl-NL"));
```

This will parse `"13/10/2013"` also.

Answer (score 1):

ParseExact needs the day parsed to be in the exact format specified:

So either:

```
string datum = "13/7/2013";
DateTime dtDatum = DateTime.ParseExact(datum, "d/M/yyyy", CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("nl-NL"));
```

or

```
string datum = "2013-13-7";
DateTime dtDatum = DateTime.ParseExact(datum, "yyyy-d-M", CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("nl-NL"));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
string datum = "13/7/2013";
DateTime dtDatum = DateTime.ParseExact(datum, "d/M/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Comment: Hum ... I wonder why `DateTime dtDatum = DateTime.ParseExact(datum, "d/M/yyyy", CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("nl-NL"));` is invalid ?